# calculating Möbius function

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I wonder if there is any efficient way to calculate Möbius function for a array of number 1:1000000

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a few papers that might be helpful.

Shallit and Shamir, Number-theoretic functions which are equivalent to number of divisors, Inform. Process. Lett. 20 (1985), no. 3, 151–153, MR0801982 (86k:11076). The review, by Hale Trotter, says $\mu(n)$ can be calculated from a single value $d(n^q)$ where $d$ is the divisor function and $q$ is a prime greater than $1+\log_2n$.

Lioen and van de Lune, Systematic computations on Mertens' conjecture and Dirichlet's divisor problem by vectorized sieving, in From Universal Morphisms to Megabytes: a Baayen Space Odyssey, 421–432, Math. Centrum, Centrum Wisk. Inform., Amsterdam, 1994, MR1490603 (98j:11125). The review, by Jonathan P. Sorenson, says the authors present sieving algorithms for computing $\mu(n)$.

Herman te Riele, Computational sieving applied to some classical number-theoretic problems, in Number Theory in Progress, Vol. 2 (Zakopane-Kościelisko, 1997), 1071–1080, de Gruyter, Berlin, 1999, MR1689561 (2000e:11119). The review, by Marc Deléglise, starts, "This paper is a survey about different applications of sieving in number theory. Finding all the primes belonging to a given interval and computing all the values of the Möbius function on a given interval are obvious examples."

Answer (score 12):

You don't need the bigger machinery of a segmented sieve for such a small range.  Here is a simple $O(n\log\log n)$ algorithm to calculate all $\mu(i)$ up to $n$ based on the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  In fact, the sieve **does** fully factor all the square-free numbers; it just doesn't do it one at a time.

Depending on your computer, this approach is practical up to around $2^{30}$ at which point you need to start using higher-precision arithmetic and computing a range of $\mu(i)$ values in batches.

```
public static int[] GetMu(int max)
{
    var sqrt = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(max));
    var mu = new int[max + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
        mu[i] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++)
    {
        if (mu[i] == 1)
        {
            for (int j = i; j <= max; j += i)
                mu[j] *= -i;
            for (int j = i * i; j <= max; j += i * i)
                mu[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (mu[i] == i)
            mu[i] = 1;
        else if (mu[i] == -i)
            mu[i] = -1;
        else if (mu[i] < 0)
            mu[i] = 1;
        else if (mu[i] > 0)
            mu[i] = -1;
    }
    return mu;
}
```

Running `GetMu(1000000)` takes about 10 msec on my computer.

Comment: Doing it the second-most-stupid-way, as described in my answer with Mathematica takes 1sec. I did not try it using Gerhard's extra-stupid way, but it is safe to say that anything works in this range.

Comment: So, how many different spellings of Eratosthenes can we accumulate in this thread?

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks.  Fixed here ... and in all my other documents.

Comment: In Rick Sladkey's answer, it seems to me that after running through the sieve, mu[i] should be 0 or +/- i. So why have the extra conditions: else if (mu[i] < 0) mu[i] = 1; else if (mu[i] > 0) mu[i] = -1; ??

Comment: It's not true that all the prime factors of a number are less than its square root. But, if there is such a factor, there can only be one.

Answer (score 9):

For range 1:1000000 the stupidest possible algorithm (factor each integer, check if it's square free, raise -1 to the right power) will terminate in a blink of an eye. For much larger ranges, an obvious modifican of the sieve of erathsosphenes will be very fast ( just remember to zero every $p$th number at the $p$th step.

Comment: I want to avoid factoring it. I'm also considering Sieve of Eratosthenes 

Comment: You might consider a wheel method: when you have data for the primes below q, make q^2 copies and modify the concatenation by tweaking every qth entry.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.13

Comment: Calling any algorithm the "stupidest possible" underestimates the power of human ingenuity....

Comment: @Greg: I double dog dare ya :)

Comment: For calclulating mu(n) when n>1,  pick a prime p at random.  If n/p is an integer, use (-1) times  mu(n/p), taking care to check if p divides n/p.  Otherwise go back and try again.  There are stupider variations of course.  Gerhard "Dare You Double-Dog  Dare Me?" Paseman, 2012.06.13

Comment: Is erathsosphenes what you get when you cross Eratosthenes with Aristophanes?

Comment: @Gerhard: I should have known better than to dare you :)
@Gerry: Yeah, that's it.

Answer (score 7):

The key phrase here is **for an array**.  Then try the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

> - initialize an array of length N of 1's
> - for each prime $p < N$ iterate over the array:
>
>   - multiply each $x \equiv 0 \, (\mod p\,)$ by $-1$
>   - set each $x \equiv 0 \, (\mod p^2)$ to $\;\,0$

We stop at power $2$ since we are just looking for squarefree ([OEIS: A005117](https://oeis.org/A005117)).

This is certainly not the fastest but maybe easiest to implement.  I downloaded a list of [primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/) off the internet (or you can generate or find your own sieve).

```
import numpy as np

L = np.ones(100000).astype(int)

for p in P:
    L[::p]    *= -1
    L[::p**2] *=  0
```

The output looks good (See also [OEIS:A008683](https://oeis.org/A008683))

```
0,  1,  -1, -1,  0, -1,  1, -1,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0, -1,  1,  
1,  0,  -1,  0, -1,  0,  1,  1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -1
```

---

#### The Sieve

```
N = np.ones(100000).astype(int)
N[:2] = 0

P = []

p = 1
while p < np.sqrt(100000):

    p = np.argmax(N)
    N[::p] = 0
    P += [p]

P = np.hstack((P, np.where(N > 0)[0]))
P[100:105]
```

This is a sample implementation.  The results, they look correct:

> 547, 557, 563, 569, 571

Comment: I think you want to not just 'replace 1 by -1' but just 'multiply each entry $\equiv 0\pmod p$ by -1'; your code itself gets it right, but the description suggests that once a value has been set to -1 it can't be flipped back.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki just noticed I have reproduce Section 3 in [Systematic computations on Mertens' conjecture and Dirichlet's divisor problem by vectorized sieving](http://walter.lioen.com/papers/LL94.pdf) referred to in the checked answer.

Comment: You may sieve and find primes at the same time as computing the mobius function

Comment: Also I think the primes must be up to $N$, since considering only $p < \sqrt N$ obviously misses all the primes above $\sqrt N$.

Answer (score 4):

I also like thisone, $\mathcal{O}(N \ln N)$ additions being not so different to $\mathcal{O}(N \ln \ln N)$ multiplications

```
% N(1+ln N) additions/affectations. an array of 2 bits elements would be enough

% matlab 
function mu = computeMu(N)
    mu = zeros(1,N); mu(1) = 1; 
    % Will compute the Dirichlet inverse of any sequence starting with 1
    for n = 1:N
        mu(n+n:n:end) = mu(n+n:n:end) - mu(n);
    end
end
```

Comment: Very fast and elegant. This doesn't compute the Dirichlet inverse, but rather the Mobius transform $f(x) = x \ast \mu$, right?

Comment: You also only need to go up to N/2+1.